# Daily agenda for all Google owned calendars

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get daily agenda of the events from all my calendars (personal, holidays, specific tasks etc) sent in one email.

I use the following code for one specific calendar, but don't know how to add all other owned calendars in the same code, is that even possible?

```
function sendAllCalendarsAgenda() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarById('?????????@group.calendar.google.com');
  var events = cal.getEventsForDay(new Date());
  var mailto = 'myEmailAddress@gmail.com';

  if (events.length > 0) {
    var body = 'Google Calendar - Events' + 'nn';
    var tz = Session.getScriptTimeZone();

    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      body += Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), tz, 'MM:dd HH:mm') + ' ～ ';
      body += Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getEndTime(), tz, 'MM:dd HH:mm') + ' :';
      body += events[i].getTitle() + 'n';
    }

    MailApp.sendEmail(mailto, 'Google Calender - Summary', body);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this:

function sendAllCalendarsAgenda() {
  const cals = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  let o = [];
    var body = 'Google Calendar - Events Summary' + '\n\n';
    cals.forEach(cal => {
      var events = cal.getEventsForDay(new Date());
      var mailto = 'myEmailAddress@gmail.com';
      if (events.length > 0) {
        var tz = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          body += event[i].getTitle();
          body += Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), tz, 'MM:dd HH:mm') + ' ～ ';
          body += Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getEndTime(), tz, 'MM:dd HH:mm') + ' :';
        }
        o.push(body);
      }
    });
    MailApp.sendEmail(mailto, 'Google Calendar - Summary', a.join('\n\n'));
}
```